# Profiling options not working with gloss

Tags: haskell, gloss

Profiling options aren't working with gloss, even though gloss was installed with library profiling enabled in `~/.cabal/config`,

Example: Test.hs

```
import Graphics.Gloss
main = display (InWindow "test" (800, 600) (200, 200)) black blank
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ ghc Test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test ...
$ ./Test +RTS -s
```

I then close the window with window's x button, but there isn't any gc output.

If I change Test.hs to `main = print "test"` and repeat the steps, it outputs some garbage collection related info, which is what should be happening.

Comment: When the main glut window closes, it exits the entire program. You can set the [`actionOnWindowClose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.2.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Begin.html) variable, but that requires editing the source code of gloss.

Answer (score 0):

When profiling with Graphics.Gloss, you will need to explicitly handle the end of the program in your code. You might want to hardcode a timeout for the animation, or catch some keyboard input and manually end the program (using something as simple as `unsafePerformIO exitSuccess`).

The `actionOnwindowClose` seems to be on the wishlist of the gloss devs, but is not working at the moment (https://github.com/benl23x5/gloss/blob/b41f867ffb6c05a40f778a29f99933b603c11a31/gloss/Graphics/Gloss/Internals/Interface/Backend/GLUT.hs#L61)